# How to use Vue3 via CDN on Django without NodeJs bundler?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, vuejs3

On Vue2 I just add the CDN then I have Vue available on my js files, but Vue3 I could not do the same - My js files does not detect Vue. How can I solve it in order to use Vue3?

Comment: use cdn to load vue.js

Comment: @Thiago I'v got an example fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/dapo/Ly0zdcb4/ seems to be working fine. Can you clarify what issue you're having?

Comment: @Daniel, follow the the link to the git repository working on Django with Vue2: https://github.com/u7540936/ToDoApp_Django_Vue2. In Static > vue_axios folder, I have vue.js (Vue2), axios and the the "Main.js". Probably it is some simple different from Vue2 I did not figure out yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to include the new vue js file

You can get source from here https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.5/dist/vue.global.js and link or include in your project

I cut out some stuff (axios, methods, template, etc.) But this should give you an idea.

The important parts...

- use `createApp` from Vue either using `Vue.createApp` or using destructuring
- `data` **needs** to be a function that returns an object

#### Example:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  data() {
    return {
      returned_task: '',
      new_task: '',
      create_modify: '',
      modify_id: -1,
      modify_index: -1,
      tasks: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.tasks = ['do this ‍', 'and that '];
  },
});

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.5/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in tasks">[[task]]</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks. After the example above, I looked to the docs again and could make it works fully in my Django App. I upload it to the git in order to make it easy to compare Vue2 and Vue3. On Git, Vue2 is on Branch 1.0 and Vue3 is on Branch 2.0. Follow the link: https://github.com/u7540936/ToDoApp_Django_Vue2/blob/2.0/static/vue_axios/main.js

Comment: and for... fun... there's also a composition example https://jsfiddle.net/dapo/0e972mxd/

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. Now I will be playing to learn a bit more about Vue3.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  data() {
    return {
      returned_task: '',
      new_task: '',
      create_modify: '',
      modify_id: -1,
      modify_index: -1,
      tasks: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.tasks = ['do this ‍', 'and that '];
  },
});

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.5/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in tasks">[[task]]</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.